# Use 3 time quotes in a PHP echo with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Iam trying to execute a script with PHP and there I got a Problem with the Quotes.
How do I do, if I need 3 times Quotes in ONE String? Here my Prob:

```
echo "
  <script>
     $('input[name=plattformStreamer1][value='youtube']').prop('checked',true);
  </script>
";
```

I have in PHP at the beginning the Double-Quotes to open the echo. After that I use the Single Quotes for the jQuery Selection and than I use them also in the Selector. I feel kinda stupid that I get no Solution :D

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest solution is to drop out of PHP to output the JS code.

```
?>
  <script>
     $(input[name=plattformStreamer1][value='youtube']).prop('checked',true);
  </script>
<?php
```

Answer (score 2):

Use backslash

```
echo "
  <script>
     $('input[name=plattformStreamer1][value=\'youtube\']').prop('checked',true);
  </script>
";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can escape those string with backslash, or use heredoc

```
echo <<<EOL
  <script>
     $("input[name=plattformStreamer1][value='youtube']").prop('checked',true);
  </script>
EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

All the other answer will work as well but I like to use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) or [vsprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.vsprintf.php) if you are building html a lot in PHP and then outputting it. Basically you can build up your parameters and then pass them to what you want them to look like.

`sprintf` you have to set each param as an argument. It can be direct but I used variables.

```
//You can parameter your html
$value = "youtube";
$prop = "checked";

$input = sprintf("<script>$(input[name=plattformStreamer1][value='%s']).prop('%s',true); </script>",$value,$prop);

echo $input;
```

`vsprintf` acts the same but takes an array:

```
$arr = ["youtube","checked"];

$input = vsprintf("script>$(input[name=plattformStreamer1 [value='%s']).prop('%s',true); </script>",$arr);

echo $input;
```